# NodeJS Crypto createCipher('aes128') equivalent in browser?

Tags: node.js, cryptography, aes, cryptojs

server code:

```
cipher = createCipher('aes128', 'password');
str = cipher.update('message', 'utf8', 'base64');
str += cipher.final('base64')
```

I want the client code (the browser) have the same algorithm as above, given the same message and password, produce the same output as the server's.

I tried `CryptoJS`, `SJCL` and some other libraries, but they use `iv` and `salt` which makes the result entirely different. In my situation, that security isn't necessary.

(I don't know exactly what `iv` and `salt` is, I just hope the code can function without them.)

**UPDATE:** I find that without proper knowledge of the encryption itself, using the function in this way is a huge mistake.
Per [doc](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createdecipheriv_algorithm_key):

> password is used to derive key and IV, which must be a 'binary'
>   encoded string or a buffer.

I'm going to learn some basics first.

Comment: [IV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) and [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) are both critical to proper crypto with AES. Doing crypto in the browser is potentially quite a security hole, however, because you're exposing your crypto secrets (password, salt, etc.) to the entire world. Why do you need to encrypt in the browser? Consider using ajax to have the server do the crypto for you.

Comment: @MattBall yes I googled and I was scared by the vector math.

Comment: You don't need to understand every detail of how it works to understand why they're important. I'm still curious to know why you think it's necessary to do the actual crypto in the browser rather than delegating to the server.

Comment: you are right, I'll go over it again.